# Magento 2.3.3 : Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Summary::appendSummaryFieldsToCollection()

Tags: magento2

i have just upgrade to magento 2.3.3 and now i am gettting erorr like

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Summary::appendSummaryFieldsToCollection() must be an instance of
 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection, instance of Ced\CsMarketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor\Collection given, called in 
 //vendor/magento/module-review/Observer/CatalogProductListCollectionAppendSummaryFieldsObserver.php on line 57 and defined in
 //vendor/magento/module-review/Model/ResourceModel/Review/Summary.php:87 Stack trace: #0
 //vendor/magento/module-review/Observer/CatalogProductListCollectionAppendSummaryFieldsObserver.php(57):
 Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Summary->appendSummaryFieldsToCollection(Object(Ced\CsMarketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor\Collection), '5', 'product') #1
 //vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Review\Observer\CatalogProductListCollectionAppendSummaryFieldsObserver->e in
 //vendor/magento/module-review/Model/ResourceModel/Review/Summary.php on line 87
```

any one have idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is from **module Ced\CsMarketplace**, you need to disable it or contact the support team of the company which provides this module.